# can't coverage onClick in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have difficulty covering this part of the code **( ) => setActive(!active)}**.

my function :

```
export default function FunctionHeader({ children, active, setActive }) {
    return (
        <FunctionHeaderStyled onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>
                {children}
            <ArrowStyled
                src={arrowIcon}
                alt="arrow icon"
                style={{transform: active ? "rotate(180deg)" : "rotate(0deg)",}}
            />
        </FunctionHeaderStyled >
    );
```

my test:

```
describe("Test FunctionHeader", () => {
  it("component rendering test", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<FunctionHeader header={''}><div>test</div></FunctionHeader>);
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

I would appreciate a support.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not passing the props to the `FunctionHeaerheader` component, you need to pass the `onClick` and `active` props along with your already passed `children`.

Then you must find the component that you wish by it's classname, role, etc

```
describe("Test FunctionHeader", () => {
  it("component rendering test", () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn(() => 'onClick');
    const active = true; // or false - up to you

    const wrapper = mount(
        <FunctionHeaderStyled 
            onClick={onClick}
            active={active}
            >
            <div>test</div>
        </FunctionHeaderStyled>);

    // something like this
    const button  = wrapper.find('button')
    // or
    // you could also try to find the button with the FunctionHeaderStyled class
    const headerStyled = wrapper.find('.your-FunctionHeaderStyled-className');
    
    expect(button.length).toBe(1);
    expect(headerStyled.length).toBe(1);

    // optional - simulate a click on the button
    button.simulate('click');
    // should work too
    // headerStyled.simulate('click');

    expect(onClick).toEqual('onClick');
    // also this one
    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And optionally, once you've find the DOM element that triggers your `onClick`, you can `simulate` a click and assert that it has been called.

Finally, I'd recommend you to use [React Testing Library](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/block-layout) to make your React test. It's based on `Jest` and will make your life easier.